# Regex less than or greater than 0

Tags: regex

I'm trying to find a regex that validates for a number being greater or less than 0.

It must allow a number to be 1.20, -2, 0.0000001, etc...it simply can't be 0 and it must be a number, also means it can't be 0.00, 0.0

```
^(?=.*[1-9])(?:[1-9]\d*\.?|0?\.)\d*$
```

tried that but it does not allows negative

Comment: Regex is the wrong tool for that.

Comment: Don't use regex for maths! In what environment do you use this, what programming language?

Comment: This is close: `0 | (\b0\.0+\b)` but not perfect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

also tried something:

```
-?[0-9]*([1-9][0-9]*(\.[0-9]*)?|\.[0-9]*[1-9][0-9]*)
```

demo: http://regex101.com/r/bZ8fE5

Answer (score 8):

I don't think a regex is the appropriate tool for that problem.

Why not using a simple condition ?

```
long number = ...;

if (number != 0)
{
    // ...
}
```

Why using a bazooka to kill a fly ?

Comment: Just to be more exact: If the input is a string, `double.TryParse()` or similar has to be done first.

Comment: @Joe: Yes, you are right. But OP has not specified the language he is using, so I cannot provide a more complete example...

Comment: @Pierre because it is a godzila type fly :) lol I really do not wish to get into as to why I am needing this regex as opposed to doing it programatically.  But thank you for the input regardless.

Answer (score 1):

Just tried something:

`[+-]?(?:\d*[1-9]\d*(?:\.\d+)?|0+\.\d*[1-9]\d*)`

[Online demo](http://regex101.com/r/pQ4rK4)

Comment: loving the demo, was using a much worse website before - thanks!

Comment: @MichaSchwab you're welcome, note that it's based on PHP PCRE which may differ from other regex engines qua capabilities.

Comment: Good to know, thanks, but perfect, I'm mostly writing PHP atm anyways :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try to negate the regex like this

```
!^[0\.]+$
```

If you're feeling the need to use regex just because it's stored as a String you could use `Double.parseDouble()` to covert the string into a numeric type. This would have an added advantage of checking if the string is a valid number or not (by catching `NumberFormatException`).

Answer (score 0):

Take a typical regex for a number, say

```
^[+-]?[0-9]*(\.[0-9]*)?$
```

and then require that there be a non-zero digit either before or after the decimal. Based on your examples, you're not expecting leading zeros before the decimal, so a simple regex might be

```
^([+-]?[1-9][0-9]*(\.[0-9]*)?)|([+-]?[0-9]*\.0*[1-9]*0*)
```

Then decide if you still want to use a regex for this.